# QGIS 3.0 - No GDAL Tools work

Tags: gdal, qgis-processing, mac, qgis-3

In QGIS 3.0, none of my GDAL raster tools work (toold in Raster Analysis, Raster Conversion, etc). I've been able to find workarounds because many of these tools are available in other toolboxes.

Example: The Processing Toolbox has a "Slope" tool. Here is a screenshot of my parameters:
[image]

Adding to the confusion, my log is not helpful. Screenshot below:
[image]

Can anyone offer me some pointers?

Comment: do you have a space in your file location? try placing albemarle_dem.dem in c:/temp and running

Comment: see  [KingChaos:QGIS 3 Tools & Processing Workaround](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180406_qgis_tools_processing_workaround)

Comment: The log is helping a lot. The message in blue: 'gdaldem not found'. It might be a problem with the installation on mac

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm adding an updated answer as the above link to KyngChaos's page is now an inactive page. I dug this answer out of an [obscure thread on osgeo-org](http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/GDAL-processing-scripts-not-working-on-QGIS3-mac-td5359638.html) in which William Kyngesburye commented on.

Quote from the thread: "It looks like a PATH problem - there used to be a configuration to set the GDAL tools path, but it's missing in QGIS 3, though there is still a preference setting saved."

So here is what to do:

In QGIS in the top left click on "QGIS 3" > "Preferences". Scroll down and find "environment" and add a PATH as follows:

[image]
The text, so you can copy and paste (remove the quotes):
"/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:"

It looks to me like QGIS doesn't know where to look to find the GDAL tools, which is why the raster tools are not working.

Answer (score 0):

@Gene provided a solution.  See the following link:

[KingChaos:QGIS 3 Tools & Processing Workaround](http://www.kyngchaos.com/blog/2018/20180406_qgis_tools_processing_workaround)

Comment: Link appears to be broken.